# Xampp Installation stuck at bitnami Logo

Tags: installation, xampp, bitnami

I would just like to ask on how could I fix this bug on installing XAMPP on my computer. I Have attached an image of my xampp installer here:
[image: xampp installer here] so I could refer it to you guys.

Ok so here comes my problem. Whenever I try to open up my XAMPP installer. It just stucks up after the bitnami logo thingy pops up:
[image: bitnami logo thingy pops up] and then it does not shows the installer after. I already changed my UAC Settings on "Never Notify" but still it's still not working. And when I open my task manager, I could see that there is a xampp process that's running:
[image: xampp process that's running]. I would really appreciate all the help I can get here.

Comment: Inline images; trademark capitalization; grammar; noise reduction.

Comment: Could you take a look to the solutions provided in the docs below to deal with Antivirus blocking the installer?

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/#how-to-configure-anti-virus-software-to-work-with-bitnami-stacks